# How to use css control to focus on div background when href link clicked

Tags: html, css, href

Im trying to put `:focus` on div so it will focus with other colors when href link is clicked, is it possible ?? Any help would be appreciated.

Below are my current progress

`eg:` [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/v7xv076b/9/)

Expected result, when click on the href link, it will focus on the div background (like hover do).

[image]

i have no idea how to convert this to javascript

```
 $("#colOne ul li").click(function(){
 $("#colOne ul li").removeClass("active");
 $(this).addClass("active")
 })
```

Comment: can you explain exactly what you want??? if you are trying to get the focus an element you can use :active instead..

Comment: hi @Aru, question updated with example. From the example you can see that when mousehover to href link the div background is changing to light green color. Yes, i want to make the same when i click on the href link it will focus on light green even when i mouseout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need li action so you need to use Either Jquery or Javascript. 
Use following JavaScript will solve your issue.

HTML:

```
<div id="colOne">
    <h3>Fruit</h3>
    <div class="bg1">
        <ul>
            <li class="litest"><a href="" target="entryFrame">Apple</a></li>
            <li class="litest"><a href="" target="entryFrame">Orange</a></li>
            <li class="litest"><a href=""  target="entryFrame">Banana</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script language="javascript">
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("litest");

for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; ++i){

    buttons[i].onmousedown = function() {
        this.setAttribute("class", "active");
    }
}
</script>
```

You can use  `this.classList.toggle('active');` instead of `this.setAttribute("class", "active");` to add and remove effect.

Check [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v7xv076b/13/).

If you like to use JQuery use following JQuery code:

```
$(function(){
    $("li").bind("click", function(){
         $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

**Edit:**

Here i edited my fiddle as per your requirement.

Check [Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/v7xv076b/15/)

Comment: Hi @ketan , the solution is so close but the only problem is when i click on second item it will active the second item too.. suppose it should be active on second item and first item will release the active ..

Comment: @user3835327 Check update fiddle in my edited answer.

Comment: Hmm.. i got for this line of code `var buttons = document.getElementById("colOne").getElementsByTagName("li");` Unable to get property 'getElementsByTagName' of undefined or null reference

Comment: Got it!! Thousand of thank to you @user3835327!! Sorry, it was my fault, i insert javascript inside `<head></head>` that's y it unable to get the property `getelementsbytagname`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want an event listener on your li's, not a :focus pseudo class.  If you set up a couple classes to reflect the colors you want, you can just switch between them on click.  I suggest [jQuery's toggleClass](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) to get this done.

Comment: Hi , is it possible done at javascript? cause i cant import jquery lib for my current program